# Spring Data Elasticsearch - Field Projections?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

As I saw Projections in Spring Data JPA documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)
but this doesn't seems to exist in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

Is there any best practices for source filtering or projections in Spring Data Elasticsearch?

I already tried creating my custom Repository and put sourceFilter with QueryBuilder. It works but I don't really want to create custom repository.

Comment: may i know what elastic search version are you using

Comment: Yes sir, I'm using 6.8.0 right now.

Comment: List<projection> projections=... I want this feature too!

Comment: did you figure this out?